# Ошибка 500 в корзине

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-500

При открытии корзины - ошибка 500. Весь остальной сайт работает нормально. Права на доступ к файлам везде одинаковые. Ситуация возникла одновременно на двух копиях сайта (работал я с одной). Обе корзины ранее работали.При включении ошибок php ложится весь сайт (No input file specified)

Comment: 500 - проблема на стороне сервера. Это не права. Допускаю ошибки в .htaccess, или php обновили и какие-то модули перестали работать. А в целом - довольно трудная в исправлении ошибка. Смотреть логи ещё надо.

Comment: htaccess - вряд ли, т. к. проблема возникла одновременно на двух копиях. php так же не обновлялся. В логах последняя ошибка 31-Aug-2018 19:32:58, ситуация возникла позже

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос закрыт. Место на хостинге было переполнено

Answer (score 0):

Наиболее частой причиной ошибки 500 (Internal Server Error, внутренняя ошибка сервера) является неверный синтаксис файла .htaccess или наличие в нем неподдерживаемых директив. Чаще всего достаточно закомментировать директиву Options (для этого нужно поставить в начале строки решетку — #), и проблема исчезнет.

Ошибка 500 также может возникать вследствие неправильного обращения с CGI-скриптами:

CGI-скрипты должны иметь окончания строк в формате UNIX (\n), а не в формате Windows (\r\n). Для этого их надо загружать на сервер по FTP в режиме ASCII.

CGI-скрипты и папки, в которых они находятся, должны быть доступны для записи только владельцу, то есть иметь права 0755 (drwxr-xr-x).

В результате работы CGI-скрипта сформированы неправильные HTTP-заголовки ответа. В этом случае для решения проблемы полезно обратиться к error_log (его можно найти в контрольной панели в разделе «Хостинг / Статистика / Лог-файлы / Ошибки»).

Comment: Директивы options в файле нет. CGI-скрипты - попробую